# Animating light dom elements using neon-elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

So i've been playing around with the neon element examples. Specifically the [load](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=neon-animated-pages&view=demo:demo/index.html) example.

I'm able to accomplish what I want but I feel there should be a more elegant way to do it. The way the example loads content is by creating an array inside of a `config` object and then uses a `dom-repeat` to stamp them out all from within animated-grid.html

This seems to force very tight coupling between the animations and the content that is being animating. I don't want to encapsulate content in side of my grid I basically want to say `Hey I want an animated grid here are the cells/content to be put inside of it` and then having the animated grid take care of laying out and animating those children

I set out to create an API that was more declarative like this.

```
<animated-grid id="grid">
  <div style="background-color: #9C27B0"> <span>1</span> </div>
  <div style="background-color: #4CAF50"> <span>2</span> </div>
  <div style="background-color: #2196F3"> <span>3</span> </div>
  <div style="background-color: #673AB7"> <span>4</span> </div>
  <div style="background-color: #FF9800"> <span>5</span> </div>
  <div style="background-color: #049688"> <span>6</span> </div>
</animated-grid>
```

I figured I could change the css selectors from `.tile` to `:host::content div`.

Then the template to

```
  <template>
    <content id='content'></content>
  </template>
```

I then took a stab at rewritting the attached method to get the children in the lightdom instead of queryselecting for .tile

```
attached: function() {
  this.async(function() {
    var nodeList = Polymer.dom(this.$.content).getDistributedNodes();
    // I only want to animate divs
    nodelist = nodeList.filter(function(node){
      return (node.nodeName === "DIV");
    });
    this.animationConfig['entry'][0].nodes = nodeList;
  });
},
```

However, I keep getting a nasty error in my console. 
[image]

The final code for animated-grid looked like this:

```
<!--
Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->
<link rel="import" href="../../../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../../paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../neon-shared-element-animatable-behavior.html">

<dom-module id="animated-grid">

  <link rel="import" type="css" href="../shared.css">

  <style>

    :host {
      display: block;
    }

    :host::content div {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
      color: white;
      vertical-align: top;
      width: calc(100% / 3);
      height: calc(100% / 2);

      @apply(--paper-font-title);
      @apply(--layout-vertical);
      @apply(--layout-center-center);
    }

    :host::content div:hover {
      @apply(--shadow-elevation-2dp);
      position:relative;
    }


  </style>

  <template>
    <content id='content'></content>
  </template>

</dom-module>

<script>

  Polymer({

    is: 'animated-grid',

    behaviors: [
      Polymer.NeonSharedElementAnimatableBehavior
    ],

    properties: {

      animationConfig: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
          return {
            'entry': [{
              name: 'cascaded-animation',
              animation: 'transform-animation',
              transformFrom: 'translateY(100%)',
              transformTo: 'none',
              timing: {
                delay: 50
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    },

    attached: function() {
      this.async(function() {
        var nodeList = Polymer.dom(this.$.content).getDistributedNodes();
        // I only want to animate divs
        nodelist = nodeList.filter(function(node){
          return (node.nodeName === "DIV");
        });
        this.animationConfig['entry'][0].nodes = nodeList;
      });
    },

    _computeTileClass: function(color) {
      return 'background-color: ' + color + '';
    }

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: A good friend pointed out that while JavaScript is still insane, it's insane for *different* reasons than erroneously listed here.  The error was that the variable being assigned into, `nodelist`, from the filter, did not have a capital "L", like the `var nodeList` does.  In JS, this means `nodelist` is now in the global variable object,  `global.nodelist`, which is why `nodeList` seemingly wasn't filtered or assigned correctly into.  So, another solution is to simply capitalize `nodelist` to `nodeList` in the filter return, and it should be fine.

Everything you're doing is fine and good (the `async` in attached is the right way to setup your `animationConfig`), with the exception of one thing.

The error you're getting is because you're attempting to animate text nodes with the `cascade-animation` you setup.

You're attempting to animate text nodes because your variable `nodeList` contains all the original 13 light dom children, which includes the text nodes, instead of just divs.

<strike>The reason your filtered array wasn't filtered, is because JavaScript is insane, and assigning into the array doesn't work as expected, like in every other language.</strike>

*A* solution is to use a new variable for the filter results:

```js
var divNodes = nodeList.filter(function(node){
  return (node.nodeName === 'DIV');
});
this.animationConfig.entry[0].nodes = divNodes;
```